# How do I change the views ajax URL?

Tags: views, ajax, search

I build a view page and have exposed filter, when I change any filters I use ajax to fetch data and re-build the content area. The ajax URL looks like

> views/ajax

I want to change the above URL to some external middleware something like below

> http://www.example.com/getData

with the existing post data. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can try changing the settings data on the `ajaxSend` event.

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(event, request, settings) {
  settings.url = '/views/ajax';
});
```